# Update Query working in MySQL workbench but not in Java code

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have created a query where I want to update some column using an inner query in the same table. And the query working fine in MySQL workbench but if I am using the same query in java then it gives me error like

```
expecting "set", found 'INNER'
```

Here is my query which I have created.

```
UPDATE table1 t1  
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(time)  
            FROM table1 WHERE id = 1) t2  
  ON t1.time = t2.time 
SET t1.fromUserId=305, 
    t1.toUserId=306,
    t1.type='Positive', 
    t1.subcategoryId=508, 
    t1.isDeleted=false,
    t1.isNotify=true;
```

Java code

```
   @Override
    public void methodName(DTOClass dtoClass) throws DatabaseException {
        logger.info("*******************In save-update ******************");
        StringBuilder saveQuery = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            saveQuery.append(" UPDATE table1 t1    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(time)  FROM table1 ");
            saveQuery.append(" WHERE id = :addedBy) t2  ON t1.time = t2.time ");
            saveQuery.append(" SET t1.fromUserId=:fromUserId, t1.toUserId=:toUserId, t1.type=:type, ");
            saveQuery.append( " t1.subcategoryId=:subcategoryId, t1.isDeleted=false, t1.isNotify=:isNotify ");
            logger.info(saveQuery.toString());
            Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(saveQuery.toString());
            query.setParameter("addedBy", dtoClass.getAddedBy());
            query.setParameter("fromUserId", dtoClass.getFromUserId());
            query.setParameter("toUserId", dtoClass.getToUserId());
            query.setParameter("type", dtoClass.getType());
            query.setParameter("subcategoryId", dtoClass.getSubcategoryId());
            query.setParameter("isNotify", dtoClass.getIsNotify());

            query.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
            throw new DatabaseException(ResourceManager.getProperty(EXCEPTION_DAO_USER));

        }

    }
```

Can someone please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add Java the code that you use?

Comment: Can you try without Inner? Make it just join, it's inner by default. It looks to me like the java mysql driver is causing the problem when parsing the query

Comment: How do you execute the query? Is it JPQL because if that's the case then it doesn't support join in update

Answer (score 1):

From your code `getCurrentSession().createQuery(saveQuery.toString());` I guess you are using some JPA implementation (spring or something? and join in update is not available in JPQL (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html#bnbud)

So you can either try to send it as a native mysql query. I am not sure what was the exact way to do that because I don't have such project here right now but I believe it was something like:
`getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(saveQuery.toString());`
Then it should work but it kinds of defeat the purpose of using JPA :)

So I guess you should just rework the query like it was proposed above:

```
update table1 set fromUserId=305, toUserId=306 where time = (SELECT MAX(time)  FROM table1 WHERE id = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Veselin Davidov, your answer was not as I wanted but it gave me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
update A
set A.fromUserId=305, 
    A.toUserId=306,
    A.type='Positive', 
    A.subcategoryId=508, 
    A.isDeleted=false,
    A.isNotify=true
from table1  A
inner join (SELECT MAX(time) as bTime  FROM table1 WHERE id = 1) B
on (A.time = (B.bTime))
```

Comment: No that's not worked. I tried that too before. It's giving me error like

"Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Remove the t1 stuff